# SimpleDateFormat parse not giving the response I expected

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have this Java class:

```
package TestPackage;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class TestSimpleDateFormat {

    private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "dd/MM/yyyy";

    private String dob;

    public boolean isValidDate(String day, String month, String year) {
        boolean isValid;
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
        formatter.setLenient(false);
        try {
            formatter.parse(extractDateOfBirthFrom(day, month, year));
            isValid = true;
        }
        catch (ParseException e){
            isValid = false;
        }
        return isValid;
    }

    private String extractDateOfBirthFrom(String day, String month, String year) {
        String dob = day.concat("/").concat(month).concat("/").concat(year);
        return dob;
    }
}
```

When I run the following in my main I get a response value of `true` for my date validation:

```
TestSimpleDateFormat testSimpleDate = new TestSimpleDateFormat();
System.out.println("Is date valid: " + testSimpleDate.isValidDate("01", "01", "81"));
```

As I'm only passing yy instead of yyyy for the year I expected the validation to fail. Is it possible to force a check for `yyyy` only?

Comment: This may be a peculiarity of this API such that passing two digits for a `yyyy` format mask is interpreted as a 4 digit year.

Comment: The documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#year) specifically mentions this: _For parsing, if the number of pattern letters is more than 2, the year is interpreted literally, regardless of the number of digits. So using the pattern "MM/dd/yyyy", "01/11/12" parses to Jan 11, 12 A.D_ . So your date is simple interpreted as January 1 of the year 81 A.D (i.e. from 23/12/2021 nearly 1941 years ago)

Comment: OK. I've reworded my question slightly. What I want to know is if there's any way to force validation where the year is `yyyy` so if `yy` is used validation will fail.

Comment: Yes: stop using the old, error-prone and badly specified `java.util.Date` / `java.util.SimpleDateFormat` classes and instead use the newer `java.time.LocalDate` / `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`

Comment: Hmm, let me look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that yy is correct, because DateFormat is taking as a valid year then you need add other validation maybe with regular expressions to validate the format of the date.

Maybe you can try:

```
try {
        String dob = main.extractDateOfBirthFrom(day, month, year);
        java.util.Date date = formatter.parse(dob);
        isValid = true;
        
        dob.matches("^([0-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])(\\/)(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))(\\/)\\d{4}$") ? isValid = true : isValid = false;
    }
    catch (ParseException e){
        isValid = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

You asked how to detect faulty input when parsing text representing a date.

```java
try 
{
    LocalDate.parse( 
        "01/01/81" , 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu" )
    )
}
catch ( DateTimeParseException e )
{
    … handle faulty input
}
```

## `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException`

[You commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70395047/simpledateformat-parse-not-giving-the-response-i-expected#comment124436562_70395047):

> if there's any way to force validation where the year is yyyy so if yy is used validation will fail.

As [Kläger responded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70395047/simpledateformat-parse-not-giving-the-response-i-expected#comment124436613_70395047), use the modern *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted the terrible legacy date-time classes such as `Date`, `Calendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu" ) ;
String input = "01/01/81" ;  // Two-digit year does not match formatting pattern.
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

That code throws an exception:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '01/01/81' could not be parsed at index 6

See this code [run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/4Np3JI).

You can trap for that [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html) to detect and handle faulty inputs.